# Filtering output of entries tag?

Tags: forms, devdemon

Forms: 3.5.3

ExpressionEngine: 2.11.1

(This started as a question, but I figured out a solution - and since it doesn't seem to be documented, I decided to post anyway as a suggestion for inclusion in the documentation and/or for anyone else in the same boat_

I'm using the Forms addon for a basic post-order customization setup, and I've used a bit of a kludge to dynamically pass an order ID number to a hidden field (basically just hardcoded the HTML for the field after the {forms:fields} & filled in its value with the {entry_id} tag). Not terribly elegant, but it works.

The problem was that I unable to find a way to limit/filter by order (when displaying submissions using the {exp:forms:entries}), to display only the customization data for the current order - if any.

Turns out that the the {exp:forms:entries} tag apparently supports the same search:field_name parameter as the {exp:channel:entries} tag:

https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/channel/channel_entries.html#search-field-name

So it worked when added **search:order_id="{segment_4}"** to the forms:entries tag:

{exp:forms:entries entry_id="XX" member_id="{author_id}" search:order_id="{segment_4}"}

The order ID is in the 4th URL segment, could have also used entry_id instead since that code is inside a channel:entries loop.

Comment: Please, ask and answer your own question, so. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the the {exp:forms:entries} tag apparently supports the same search:field_name parameter as the {exp:channel:entries} tag:

https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/channel/channel_entries.html#search-field-name

So it worked when I added **search:order_id="{segment_4}"** to the forms:entries tag:

```
{exp:forms:entries entry_id="XX" member_id="{author_id}" search:order_id="{segment_4}"}
```

The order ID is in the 4th URL segment, could have also used entry_id instead since that code is inside a channel:entries loop.